# Calculate interest without math library

Tags: function, input, double, output, calculation

I'm trying to calculate rent without math.h and pow, somehow i almost got it right, but it's not calculating the right amount and i am not sure where the issue could be, any advice on what i am missing?

```
#include <stdio.h>

double calcFutureValue(double startingAmount, double interest, int numberOfYears);

int main() {

    double startMoney, interest, futureMoney;
    int years;

    printf("Enter amount of money: ");
    scanf("%lf", &startMoney);
    getchar();

    printf("Enter interest on your money: ");
    scanf("%lf", &interest);
    getchar();

    printf("Enter amount of years: ");
    scanf("%d", &years);
    getchar();


    futureMoney = calcFutureValue(startMoney, interest, years);

    printf("In %d years you will have %.1f", years, futureMoney);
    getchar();

    return 0;
}

double calcFutureValue(double startingAmount, double interest, int numberOfYears) {

    double totalAmount;
    double interest2 = 1;


    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfYears; i++)
    {
        interest2 += interest / 100;
        totalAmount = startingAmount * interest2;
        printf("%lf", totalAmount);
        getchar();

     }

     return totalAmount;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not [*compounding* the interest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_interest) in your computation.

According to your function, `interest2 += interest / 100`.

This means that for 10 percent interest, you will have:

```
0 : 1
1 : 1.1
2 : 1.2
3 : 1.3
```

But in a compounding interest situation, the interest applies to previously-earned interest, as well as principal:

```
0 : 1
1 : 1.1
2 : 1.21
3 : 1.331
```

Try something like this:

```
interest2 = 1 + interest / 100.0;
totalAmount = startingAmount;

while (numberOfYears--) {
    totalAmount *= interest2;
}
```

Comment: Austin i tried the solution you gave, but it seems not to work, i removed the for loop and replaced it with the while loop example.

Comment: Did you initialize `totalAmount`? Updated.

Comment: Yes exactly as you wrote it above.

Comment: What result did you get?

Comment: If i input amount of money: 10000
Interest: 8
Amount of years: 3
it prints out 800.00000
64.000000
5.120000
In 3 years you will have 5.1

And i have return totalAmount; in the end of the function.

Comment: Ouch! That's a typo on my part - the `*` should be a `+` in the `interest2 = 1 + interest/100` line.

Comment: Now it works, i should be able to solve it, but i am still learning. Thanks a lot Austin!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks alot, i am always happy to get different views, i found it working when i added this though:

```
double calcFutureValue(double startingAmount, double interest, int numberOfYears) {

    double totalAmount;
    double interest2 = 1;
    double random3 = 1 + interest / 100;


    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfYears; i++)
    {
        interest2 *= random3;
        totalAmount = startingAmount * interest2;
        printf("%lf", totalAmount);
        getchar();

    }

    return totalAmount;
```